# What is the main purpose if we decline cookie in websites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, web

In my website i have cookie decline button to decline cookies. Once users decline cookie in my site Google Analytics will not work in my website. I set the code like that.

Apart from that i checked some other sites that have some option in cookie policy page to hide google adverts, facebook, twitter and youtube. Is that necessary? Actually what is the main purpose of that?

Comment: That’s because the privacy laws and the new data protection law that EU is enacting, basically giving users the right to not be tracked. That means that a cookie policy consent needs to be explicitly obtained from the user before a site can legally track the users.

Comment: @Terry i have portal in my website. I stored some cookie value in my website. Am i need to clear that cookies when users decline cookies?

Comment: In most cases, cookies contain **personally identifiable** data (eg the cookies used by google analytics). These cookies cannot be stored, created, or emitted to third party services if the user declines to be tracked. However, there are some cookies that do not contain data granular enough to personally identify somebody, eg if you are storing screen resolutions and user agent string in the cookie for usage statistics :) even though IP addresses cannot reliably identify somebody, under most jurisdictions it will be considered as personally identifiable data.

Comment: @Terry for eg in my site i stored my sister concern company url and my pagenation url in cookies.These both are fine? or am i need to remove?

Answer (score 2):

Ads are intrusive, so EU wanted them out, marketers wouldn't agree, so they wanted to make consent mandatory. I think you could still use cookies, but if you do, you have to take consent, and it is best not find a workaround. I am sure you have already seen this, if not, here is a [guidelines document](https://ico.org.uk/media/for-organisations/documents/1545/cookies_guidance.pdf) I would want to read before I make any modifications on my website. There is no specific mention of an HTTP cookie website, but please be careful with these rules, anybody(your competitor per say) could complain on your website, and it may be investigated. I do not know of any serious adherence cases, but there could be compliance issues. Good luck!